# On "minimal presentation" of local rings essentially of finite type over a field

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, ra.rings-and-algebras, localization, krull-dimension

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Let $(R,\mathfrak m)$ be a local ring essentially of finite type over $k$ (https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/07DR).  Then, $R$ is the homomorphic image of a localization of some polynomial ring over $k$.

My question is: Does there exist a surjective $k$-algebra homomorphism $k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]_P \to R$, for some integer $n\geq 0$ and prime ideal $P $ of $k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$,  such that $\mu(\mathfrak m)=\dim k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]_P $?

(Here, $\mu(\mathfrak m)$ is the minimal number of generators of $\mathfrak m$).

Some obvious thoughts: I think it is enough to show that there exists integer $n\geq 0$ and prime ideal $P $ of $k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]$ such that $R \cong \dfrac{ k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]_P}{I}$ for some ideal $I$ contained in the square of the maximal ideal of $k[X_1,\ldots, X_n]_P$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R$ is the local ring of the point $P$ on a smooth $n$-dimensional $k$-variety $V$ then any such homomorphism would be an isomorphism. So it cannot exist if $V$ is irrational. For example, take $V$ to be an elliptic curve.